# CSS grid - setting 2 columns with different background to full screen width, with content of both of them to joint max-width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a layout where the whole content should take the `max-width` of `1440px`. In the layout I have an app bar with 2 columns each on one end, and 2 columns in the content part of the page. One smaller serving as a drawer, the other taking the rest of the space. The content in this 2 columns should be aligned with the content from the app bar. I am not sure how to make that kind of layout, since the 2 columns from the content should also have a different `background color`, I have tried something like this for the layout:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.drawer-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ececec;
  justify-items: end;
  display: grid;
}

.drawer {
  display: grid;
  width: 350px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  height: max-content;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  justify-items: start;
}

.main {
  max-width: 1190px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.editor-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.editor-content {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.right-part {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-bar">
  <div class="bar-content">
    <div class="left-part">
      <p>link</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-part">
      <p>user</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="drawer-wrapper">
    <div class="drawer">
      <p>Some link</p>
      <p>Some link</p>
      <p>Some link</p>
      <p>Some link</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cookies-ol83v), and the result [here](https://ol83v.codesandbox.io/). As you can see in the result link the content of the 2 columns is not properly aligned with the content from the `app-bar`. How can I make that aligned with each other?

Comment: what do you mean by content of 2 columns not aligned with the content of `app-bar`?  As I see there is no content in the `app-bar`.Do you want  `Some link` to be aligned below the `navbar-link`?

Comment: Indeed, some idea of what this is supposed to look like would be useful....but I'd start with a proper CSS reset to remove **all** default margins.

Comment: @SaiManoj  Yes, I want link and user from the app bar to be aligned with the content of the 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment I have edited your code. Please let me know if you were looking for the same

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container-nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px
}

.drawer-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ececec;
  justify-items: start;
  display: grid;
}

.drawer {
  display: grid;
  width: 350px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  height: max-content;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  justify-items: start;
}

.main {
  max-width: 1190px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.editor-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.editor-content {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.right-part {
  justify-self: end;
}

.drawer p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.holder{
max-width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="container-nav">
    <div class="">
      <p>link</p>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:0px 24px">
      <p>user</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="drawer-wrapper">
      <div class="drawer">
        <p>Some link</p>
        <p>Some link</p>
        <p>Some link</p>
        <p>Some link</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid having margins around the page

Comment: You can reset the default margins using `*{margin:0}` before you start the project as paulie mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you mean now. First, you have to give .container the same max-width as your .bar-content (max-width: 1440px, and margin:0 auto). Then add these rules:

```
.drawer-wrapper,.main-wrapper {position:relative;}

.drawer-wrapper:before,.main-wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.drawer-wrapper:before {
    left: -50vw;
    background:#ececec;
}

.main-wrapper:before {
    right: -50vw;
    background: blue;
}
```

Optionally add  justify-self: start and padding-left: 20px to your .drawer element to left align it to the text on your app bar.

We could also solve this by wrapping .container in another div then assigning that parent div with linear gradient background that matches your color for each half.

```
<div class="container-bg">
<div class="container">...</div>
</div>


.container {
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.container-bg {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ececec 50%, blue 50%);
}
```

Comment: Basically you want the left sidebar bar to take up the rest of the space on the left with its own color, then the rest of the content will take up the rest of the space on the right with its own background color, also? But both of the left bar and the content should be centered and will only expand up to the max width, right?

Answer (score -1):

```
.drawer p {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

add this in css, will make it aligned with each other.